# How to delete a range of characters from every line from a string?

Tags: python, string

I have the following string and I would like to remove every 6th to 11th character for every line.

```
string = ('''

00:00:100:00:00

00:00.711,00:00

00:00,2()!00:00

''')
```

So far I was only able to remove the characters from the 1st line. How do I do it to repeat it for every sigle line?

Did:

```
x = string[6:11]

print(string.replace(x, ''))
```

Got:

```
00:0000:00

00:00.711,00:00

00:00,2()!00:00
```

Want:

```
00:0000:00

00:0000:00

00:0000:00
```

Comment: You can split the string by space using `string.split()`. Then you can loop over the resulting substrings and build a new string with your changes.

Comment: RomanPerekhrest thanks for reply.  I indented every line for the writing this question because this is how I seet it on Visual Studio code. This probably  why the output does not seem correct.

Answer (score 2):

`split` the string on newlines, take the desired substring of each line, and then `join` it back:

```
>>> string = ('''
...
... 00:00:100:00:00
...
... 00:00.711,00:00
...
... 00:00,2()!00:00
...
... ''')
>>> print('\n'.join(line[:5] + line[10:] for line in string.split('\n')))


00:0000:00

00:0000:00

00:0000:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reformat the entry string and split it, then only take the first 5 and last 5 characters:

```
string = (''' 00:00:100:00:00 00:00.711,00:00 00:00,2()!00:00 ''')
elements = string.strip().split()
[element[:5]+element[-5:] for element in elements]
# ['00:0000:00', '00:0000:00', '00:0000:00']
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the string needs to be split into a list using `lst = string.split("\n")`. Then, we need to loop through the elements in this list, using a for loop.

Now, their are two main routes:

The first way is using `new_lst.append(i[:5]+i[10:])`. This basically takes the first 5 elements of the line, and combines it with every element after the 10th.

The other way, which is commented in the code below, is `new_lst.append(i.replace(str(i[5:10]), ""))` This is what you were doing, where you take the 5th to 10th characters and you search for them in the string and replace them with `""`, which is nothing.

Both ways work, although the first is slightly better.

Here is the code:

```py
string = ('''

00:00:100:00:00

00:00.711,00:00

00:00,2()!00:00

''')

lst = string.split("\n")
new_lst = []
for i in lst:
    new_lst.append(i[:5]+i[10:])
    #new_lst.append(i.replace(str(i[5:10]), ""))

string = "\n".join(new_lst)
print(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

A string in Python has a `splitlines` method. Combined with a list comprehension and some slicing this is pretty straightforward.

```
>>> string = ('''
... 
... 00:00:100:00:00
... 
... 00:00.711,00:00
... 
... 00:00,2()!00:00
... 
... ''')
>>> string.splitlines()
['', '', '00:00:100:00:00', '', '00:00.711,00:00', '', '00:00,2()!00:00', '']
>>> [line[:6] + line [11:] for line in string.splitlines() if line != '']
['00:00:0:00', '00:00.0:00', '00:00,0:00']
```

Though it appears that your requirement of removing the 6th through 11th characters doesn't actually correspond to your expected output.

If we shift the bounds by one, we can get your expected output.

```
>>> [line[:5] + line [10:] for line in string.splitlines() if line != '']
['00:0000:00', '00:0000:00', '00:0000:00']
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also use a specific pattern capturing the leading and trailing digits with the colon, and match 5 characters in between.

Then use a replacement keeping only the 2 captured parts.

```
^(\d\d:\d\d).{5}(\d\d:\d\d)$
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ppKTtv/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HON4JJ).

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"^(\d\d:\d\d).{5}(\d\d:\d\d)$"

s = ("00:00:100:00:00\n\n"
    "00:00.711,00:00\n\n"
    "00:00,2()!00:00")

result = re.sub(pattern, r"\1\2", s, 0, re.M)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
00:0000:00

00:0000:00

00:0000:00
```

Comment: Thank you the The fourth bird! I didn't know how to use with regex.